# Jquery: two tables side by side

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am having trouble creating two tables side by side (simulating deal or no deal money table). I know I can create a table with two columns, but I want to have a high table and a low table for easy management in the future. Here is my code:

```
amounts = [0.01, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 2500, 5000, 7500, 10000, 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 250000, 500000, 750000, 1000000] 
var tableString = "<table border=1>";
for (i = 0; i < 24; i ++){
    tableString += "<tr><td>";
    tableString += amounts[i];
    tableString += "</td></tr>";
    if (i == 11){
        var Table = $(document.createElement('span')).attr("id", "low");
        Table.html(tableString + '</table>');
        Table.appendTo(".amounts");
        tableString = "<table border=1>";
        } 
    if (i == 23){
        var Table = $(document.createElement('span')).attr("id", "high");
        Table.html(tableString + '</table>');
        Table.appendTo(".amounts");
        } 
    }
```

And my html:

```
<div class='amounts'>
</div>
```

But I dont get two tables side by side (even though I create span element). It looks exactly as if I use div element. Can someone help me?

Comment: did you inspect the dom tree using chrome dev tools or firebug?what does it look like?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/m78p6/1/

Comment: Just give the tables `display:inline-block` [See](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/gh6m5/)

Comment: @Raminson yes something like that.

Comment: @Musa how and where do I add that?

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Sorry I do not know CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be another way:

```
var amounts = [0.01, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 2500, 5000, 7500, 10000, 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 250000, 500000, 750000, 1000000] ;

function createTable(el, split){

    var tableString = "<table border=1>";


    for (var i = 0; i < el.length/2; i++){

        if(i%split == 0){ tableString += "<tr>"; }
        tableString += '<td>'+el[i]+'</td><td>'+el[i+el.length/2]+'</td>';
        if(i%split == 0){ tableString += "</tr>"; }

    }

    tableString += '</table>';
    var table = $(tableString);
    table.appendTo(".amounts");
}


createTable(amounts, 2);
```